# Join two tables where table1.id equals table2.table1_id, but only display rows from table1.id that cannot be found in table2.table1_id

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm building a form for an award where the nominees can choose multiple award categories to apply to, and answer a series of questions for each award they have chosen.

I have 2 tables.

The `first table` contains the award categories of the award:

> **id:** 1, 2, 3, ...
>
> **name:** award1, award2, award3, ....

The `second table` contains the answers with the nominee id, question id, and award category:

> **id:**
>
> **answer_id:** 1, 2, 3, ...
>
> **nominee_id:** 1, 1, 2, ...
>
> **question_id:** 1,2, 1, ...
>
> **category_id:** 1, 3, 1, ...
>
> **answer:** answer 1, answer 2, answer 3, ...

What I need is a query that can display the award categories that the nominee has already submitted answers for, as well as a second query that can display the award categories that are still available for the nominee to apply to.

So using the example above, I would like to see:

1. nominee_id 1 has already applied to award1 and award 3
2. nominee_id 1 can still apply for award 2, award 4, ...

**EDIT:**

Here are the tables, first one is the award categories, second one is the answers
[image: Here's the award categories table:]

[image: Here's the answers table]

As you can see, nominee with ID of 28 has answered a total of 16 questions, 8 per award category with id of 5 and 6.

The outputs I want are:

a) display the names of the categories nominee 28 has entered in. In this case, Brand Engagement (id:5) and Corporate Social Enterprise (id:6)

b) render a dropdown menu consisting of only the categories nominee 28 has yet to enter. In this case, award category id of 7-8.

Comment: please paste couple of records present in both table and with these records what will be your expected output? from description it is really difficult to understand the expected output

Comment: I've added screen shots of tables and clarified what I want for the output. thx!

Comment: " render a dropdown menu consisting of only the categories nominee 28 has yet to enter. In this case, award category id of 7-8." How to obtain which categories (not entered yet) he can enter?

Answer (score 0):

Try Queries as below

**Query-1**

nominee_id 1 has already applied to award1 and award 3

```
select table1.*,table2.nominee_id,table2.answer_id,table2.question_id,
table2.category_id,table2.answer from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.category_id
```

**Query-2**

nominee_id 1 can still apply for award 2, award 4, ...

```
select table1.*,table2.nominee_id,table2.answer_id,table2.question_id,
table2.category_id,table2.answer from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id <> table2.category_id
```

I have assumed fields, please ignore fields not required.

Comment: this outputs a award category name for every question the nominee has answered. So for nominee_id 28, it output 8 copies of Brand Engagement and 8 copies Corporate Social Enterprise. In the end I just made one more table storing only the nominee_id and category_id, which seems to work for now. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Ohh its ok @JosephMok

Comment: @JosephMok see my answer to get each category only once in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Sameer's answer i would suggest:

First Query (Categories with participation; effectively the same as Sameer's)

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.nominee_id, table2.answer_id, table2.question_id, table2.category_id, table2.answer
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table2.category_id = table1.id
```

Second Query (Categories with no participation; less "noise")

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.category_id = table1.id
WHERE table2.category_id IS NULL
```

The second query uses the way a `LEFT JOIN` works: if no matching row is found in table2 all columns are set to `NULL` inside the result. As the join criteria says `table2.category_id = table1.id` `table2.category_id` can only be `NULL` if `table1.id` is `NULL` or there is no row.